# How to transform config files with slow cheetah on build in a web project

Tags: msbuild, slowcheetah

So what I want to accomplish is transform all config files on the build.

- Web.config
- App.config
- ....config.xml

In the project files they all look like this:

```
<None Include="FooBar.config.xml">
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</None>
<None Include="FooBar.config.Release.xml">
  <DependentUpon>FooBar.config.xml</DependentUpon>
  <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
</None>
```

And everything works fine for windows services and windows applications. But for web projects slow cheetah is not doing the transforms. After some research I found this : 
"For web projects the files are transformed when you publish or package your application." From the slow cheetah extension page. And indeed when I publish the web project the transforms are done correctly.

So how can I change slow cheetah default behavior and execute all transforms on the build server?

Environment:

- TFS 2010
- Slow cheetah version on build server: 1.0.10727.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So how I fixed this.
I've edited the targets file of SlowCheetah

This can be found C:\Users\BuildUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v1
On your build server. Open the file and locate the following lines:

```
<BuildDependsOn Condition=" '$(IsWap)'!='true' ">
    <BuildDependsOn> 
      $(BuildDependsOn);
      TransformAllFiles
    </BuildDependsOn>
```

And i've removed the condition.

**Result:**

```
<BuildDependsOn> 
  $(BuildDependsOn);
  TransformAllFiles
</BuildDependsOn>
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no consequences in doing that? There must be a reason why that condition is there in the first place.

Comment: The condition is there so that it only happens on publish. But we don't use publish. We have custom Wix installers.

Answer (score -2):

There is a better solution these days.  Just use the transformxml msbuild task.  I don't think slow cheetah will continue to be maintained now that this functionality is native to msbuild.  More at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm afraid it works only for web.config. For app.config you still need slowcheetah